# Merge two lists using collect

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

I have 2 lists.

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D");
List<String> wife = Arrays.asList("E","F","G");
```

I have used reduce() to merge it to a single list.

```
Stream.of(names, wife)
                .reduce(new ArrayList<String>(), (list, val) -> {
                    list.addAll(val);
                    return list;
                }, 
               (list1, list2) -> {list1.addAll(list2); return list1; }));
```

How do I perform the same operation using

```
collect
```

method. I don't want to use functions from Collectors.java class. Is it possible to do it?

I tried this

```
List.of(names, wife).stream()
                .collect(new ArrayList<List<String>>(), (l1, l2) -> l1.addAll(l2));
```

However, I see that the l2 is of type List but not l1. What is l1? I want to learn how the collect method works. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Javadoc for [`Stream#collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)), you can pass `ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll` to the method to create and populate a collection such as `ArrayList`.

You could specify another concrete collection implementation besides `ArrayList`, what ever suits your needs.

To join our two lists together, I use [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)).

```java
List < String > first = List.of( "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" );
List < String > second = List.of( "E" , "F" , "G" );

List < String > result =
        Stream
                .concat( first.stream( ) , second.stream( ) )
                .collect( 
                        ArrayList :: new , 
                        ArrayList :: add , 
                        ArrayList :: addAll 
                );
```

But if you can accept any [unmodifiable `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), then it is simpler to call `toList`.

```java
List < String > result =
        Stream
                .concat( first.stream( ) , second.stream( ) )
                .toList( );
```

For more on joining streams, see [*Merging Streams in Java*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-streams) by Baeldung.com.

Comment: Before Java-16, without being concerned about mutability, one had the static `Collectors.toList()` which performs the same operations as the `collect` elaborated in the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your goal, you can simply use:

```
List<String> result = Stream.concat(names.stream(), wife.stream())
        .toList();
```

Or:

```
List<String> result = Stream.of(names, wife)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .toList();
```

Or:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(names);
result.addAll(wife);
```